# Firebase Emulator - RTDB not setting rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-tools

I've set up the emulator to test my firebase functions locally.
First problem I see is that there are created two rtdb when running the emulator:

- {PROJECT-NAME}
- {PROJECT_NAME}-default-rtdb

and I lost quite some time to understand that the functions connect to **{PROJECT-NAME}** db.

The issue is that I have a set of rules needed to perform some queries, so I set up the `firebase.json` file like this:

```
 "database": {
     "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
```

but the rules are applied to **{PROJECT_NAME}-default-rtdb** anf not **{PROJECT_NAME}**, so the queries are failing for missing `.indexOn`.

I've see multiple tickets on `firebase-tools` github repo, but are all marked as solved.

I'm using

- `firebase-tools`: 12.4.7
- `firebase-admin`: ^11.2.0
- `firebase-functions`: ^4.0.1"

How can I set the rules on the correct rtdb, or how can I change the functions' default rtdb?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I created a new empty project and moved all essential files there.

I suspect the issue was caused by `.firebasesrc` that was not added to the repo by the previous developer.

After migrating all the files, fixed the `.firebasesrc` and set the correct environment using `firebase use ...` I solved my problems.